# Using Math.max() to Calculate Max JavaScript Date Object Documentation

Tags: javascript, date, max

I'm not 100% sure why you are able to calculate the maximum date from multiple [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects using the [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function. My IDE `PhpStorm` keeps giving me the following error:

> Argument type Date is not assignable to parameter type number

It is assignable to the parameter as illustrated in my snippet:

```js
/* Variable Defaults */
var dateOne = new Date();
var dateTwo = new Date('2017-01-21');
var dateThree = new Date('11/16/2016');
var dateMax = Math.max(dateOne, dateTwo, dateThree);

/* Console Data */
console.log('dateOne', dateOne);
console.log('dateTwo', dateTwo);
console.log('dateThree', dateThree);
console.log('dateMax', dateMax + ': ' + new Date(dateMax));
```

I've decided to look into the specifications to see if maybe my IDE was using an older standard, but my research had unfulfilled my desire to educate myself why this method should work in the first place:

[ECMAScript 1st Edition (ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf)

> 15.8.2.11 max(x, y)
>
> - Returns the larger of the two arguments.
> - **If either argument is NaN, the result is NaN.**
> - If x>y, the result is x.
> - If y>x, the result is y.
> - If x is +0 and y is +0, the result is +0.
> - If x is +0 and y is -0, the result is +0.
> - If x is -0 and y is +0, the result is +0.
> - If x is -0 and y is -0, the result is -0.

[ECMAScript 5.1 (ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.11)

> 15.8.2.11 max ( [ value1 [ , value2 [ , … ] ] ] )
>
> - Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the largest of the resulting values.
> - If no arguments are given, the result is −∞.
> - **If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.**
> - The comparison of values to determine the largest value is done as in 11.8.5 except that +0 is considered to be larger than −0.
> - The length property of the max method is 2.

[ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.max)

> 20.2.2.24 Math.max ( value1, value2 , …values )
>
> - Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the largest of the resulting values.
> - If no arguments are given, the result is −∞.
> - **If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.**
> - The comparison of values to determine the largest value is done using the Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm (7.2.11) except
>     that +0 is considered to be larger than −0.
> - The length property of the max method is 2.

[ECMAScript Latest Draft (ECMA-262)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-math.max)

> 20.2.2.24 Math.max ( value1, value2, ...values )
>
> - Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the largest of the resulting values.
> - If no arguments are given, the result is -∞.
> - **If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.**
> - The comparison of values to determine the largest value is done using the Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm except that +0 is
>     considered to be larger than -0.

I've tested this method in all modern browsers and it has not generated any errors. Though I do wonder if this is compatible with older browsers.

Why does `Math.max()` work by passing in `Date` objects when the specifications clearly state that it should not?

Comment: Because of type coercion, Math.max, takes numbers.  So it will just be converting the Dates into numbers.  So PHPStorm is wrong, it looks like it's Intellisense, is talking Nonsense.

Comment: I don't know why you think "*… the specifications clearly state that it should not?*" when none of them say that. Except for the 1st, the say "*… calls ToNumber on each of the arguments…*" (which is what ed 1 did without saying so). To see how [*ToNumber*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-tonumber) treats Dates, follow the links. The short answer is, it calls *valueOf*, which returns the internal [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range), which is a number (and *might* be `NaN`, BTW).

Comment: @RobG Thanks for your explanation. I see that now. At the time I asked this question, I was under the impression that a `Date` object was `NaN`. Clearly, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a valid `Date()` is not `NaN`, it can be converted to a number using the `Number()` function, the `+` unary operator or the `valueOf()` function:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(isNaN(date) + ',' + Number(date));
console.log(isNaN(date) + ',' + +date);
console.log(isNaN(date) + ',' + date.valueOf());
console.log(isNaN(2) + ',' + Number(2));
console.log(isNaN('2') + ',' + Number('2'));
console.log(isNaN('xx') + ',' + Number('xx'));
console.log(isNaN(['a']) + ',' + Number(['a']));
console.log(isNaN({}) + ',' + Number({}));
```

Comment: You can also use `date.valueOf()` for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf

Comment: Shorter is `+date`.

Comment: @RobG You're right, but I chose `Number` for simplicity and understand-ability.

Comment: BTW, for an invalid Date, the time value is NaN, so "*Because Date() is not NaN*" is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is a special value of type number, not "everything that's not a number". It's used by functions that should return a number when it fails to do so, such as if you call `Math.sqrt(-1)`.

Furthermore, if a function expects a number, JavaScript will do it's best to make a number of whatever you give it. And since `Date` has a numeric representation (which can be obtained using `Date.valueOf`) it will use that.

(As an interesting aside, you can test whether a value is `NaN` by using the `isNaN` function, but comparing it to `NaN` directly will return `false`. Just one of those JavaScript things)